# Reviews on Mobile Site/App

Tags: discussion, review-queues

Quick question: is there a way to access the review queues on the mobile site or StackExchange app?

I don't see anything, but it seems weird to not be able to review content on the move.

Comment: No, I don't believe so.  The mobile app has links to open in a browser - I go there to find the review queue (and other functions that aren't in the app).  This may be worth asking on Meta SE

Comment: Mark, I use chrome in desktop mode (on Android) as mention by Midavalo

Comment: I do the same as Midavalo and Mapperz i.e. I use Chrome on my iPhone when I really want to get at a review queue but generally I leave that until I am back on a laptop. I think they are soon to or just have added a Safari button alongside the Chrome one.

Comment: @PolyGeo My iPhone says "Open in Safari", my Ipad says "Open in Chrome".  I don't have Chrome on my phone

Comment: @Midavalo I must have installed Chrome and made that my preference at some distant point in the past.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by several of us the way to do this on an iPhone is to first access a browser by using the button at the lower right to access this menu where I choose Open in Chrome (you may instead see Open in Safari).

[image]

Once that option is chosen you can see the review count on the screen below which can be clicked to open the review queue.

[image]

Personally, I prefer to perform reviews when I am back on a laptop but I use the above when the action to take seems simple.

If you decide to search/ask for this to be implemented in a mobile app at Meta Stack Exchange then be sure to specify whether it is iOS or Android that you are wanting because the two development cycles are far from in sync.